# How to automatically click a link when you hover over some other element? (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, hover

So I have a button in which when I hover over it, it will automatically click a link somewhere else in the site.

Is there anyway to do this in angularjs?

Comment: Does it need to click a link, or could you just have it navigate to the url on hover?

Answer (score 1):

> In angular js use ng-mouseenter which will trigger automatically when you hover to your element

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="value" ng-mouseenter="link" />
    {{link}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-mouseenter, but you need to provide an expression, if you use just the link (like in the answer above), nothing will happen.

It will be something like:

```
<button ng-mouseenter="openLink('yourLink')">Value</button>
```

And you javascript function will be something like:

```
$scope.openLink = function(link){
    window.open(link)
}
```

However, I will not recommend you to do something like that. Opening links on hover will really hurt the user experience of your site and actually, if the link is opened in a new window or a new tab will completely depend of your user's preferences in their web browser (and the popup might end up being blocked). In my opinion, if you want to open a link, just use an explicit link that your users can click on it, or use a redirect when necessary.